# Extract Week of Fiscal year from Date ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

My Fiscal Year start from 1st july to 30 June.I want to calculate weeks from start of Financial year for a year.
WEEK1,WEEK2 WEEK3...WEEK 52 ETC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FLOOR(theDate - TO_DATE('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')) / 7) + 1 AS FISCAL_WEEK
```

where `theDate` is a date between 07/01/2019 and 06/30/2020.

Comment: but its giving 53 instead of 52

Comment: 52 weeks * 7 days/week = 364 days < 1 year

Answer (score 1):

Following will give you week number in a `number` datatype

```
to_number(to_char(to_date('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')) as week_num
```

and if you want week based on ISO standard the use following

```
to_number(to_char(to_date('07/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW')) as week_num
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as OP has clearly stated that his `fiscal year starts from 1st july to 30 June`. Your query will consider 1st Jan as start of 1st week.

Comment: I have a date column in place of fixed date and fiscal year start from 1st july

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional logic:

```
select (case when extract(month from sysdate) < 7
             then floor((sysdate - trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY')) / 7) + 1
             else floor((sysdate - (trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY') + interval '6' month))/7) + 1
        end) as fiscal_week
```

This uses `sysdate` to represent the date.  You can, of course, replace it with your date column.